# Mono.Cecil MethodDefinition Variables not visible

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I've encountered a strange issue, when I try to list all of the MethodDefinition.Body.Variables in a selected method it seems to skip over a few before completing the loop. Are there any filters I need to use in order to see all variables within said method?(All of them are local variables)

```
MethodDefinition example = module.GetType("Example.Program").Methods.First(m => m.Name == "Main");
            foreach (VariableDefinition def in example.Body.Variables)
                Console.WriteLine(def.VariableType.Name);
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, especially in terms of how what you mean by "skip over a few before completing the loop" and how you're trying to "see" the variables.

Comment: a) please edit the question rather than just adding a comment; b) that's not a [mcve], it's just a snippet.

Comment: Yeah, I was apologizing while trying to figure out how to add the code snippet.

I've added the snippet now.

All I'm doing is going over the Variables collection and printing their names though there are some missing, it prints out 8 when there should be 10.

That snippet is all that I'm doing.

Comment: That's *still* just a snippet rather than a [mcve]. The point is to give us enough context to be able to just copy/paste/compile/run as far as possible. We have no idea what `Main` looks like, how it was compiled etc. Basically, until we can reproduce the problem, we're less likely to be able to help you.

Comment: I'd compare what you see in Mono.Cecil to what you see in ILSpy. I'd suspect they'd be the same. Maybe you're pointing it at an assembly built in release mode, so perhaps some of the variables have been 'optimized' away?

Comment: Thanks for the reponse Baldrick.
I've had ILSpy open in another window and can see the local variables that are not visible when iterating over them so I'm rather confused.
I've checked the Instruction count with mono.cecil then compared with Reflexil in ILSpy and they both have the same count.

Comment: Do all the missing variables have 'body' scope? Are some declared inside other blocks, such as if statements?

Comment: I don't believe so. All the variables are inside the body of the method, there's only one if statement but that references a variable that's outside of the statement.

Comment: In Reflexil, it seems that the "Variables" tab doesn't display the missing variables either.

Sorry for the new comment, couldn't edit my previous one for some reason.

Comment: Well, I feel kinda stupid. The Variables were shoved inside a private sealed class on compile which explains my issue.

(my settings didn't let me the compiler generated classes, woops)

Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my issue, it was a fault on my side.(ILSpy settings, woops)